# T-SQL Dynamic Date based on Today's Month

Tags: date, t-sql, dynamic

My fiscal year begins on April 1 and I need to include 1 full year of historical data plus current fiscal year as of today. In DAX this looks like:

```
 DATESBETWEEN(Calendar_Date
             ,IF(MONTH(TODAY()) < 4
                ,DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-2, 4, 1)
                ,DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1, 4, 1)
                )
             ,DATE(TODAY())
             )
```

I need to create this same range as a filter in a T-SQL query, preferably in the "WHERE" clause, but I am totally new to sql and have been unsuccessful in finding a solution online. Any help from more experienced people would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find these values and use as a `where` filter this is fairly straightforward date arithmetic, the logic for which you already have in your DAX code:

```
declare @dates table(d date);
insert into @dates values
 ('20190101')
,('20190601')
,('20200213')
,('20201011')
,('20190101')
,(getdate())
;

select d
      ,dateadd(month,3,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,dateadd(month,-4,d))-1,0)) as TraditionalMethod
      ,case when month(d) < 4
            then datetime2fromparts(year(d)-2,4,1,0,0,0,0,0)
            else datetime2fromparts(year(d)-1,4,1,0,0,0,0,0)
            end as YourDAXTranslated
from @dates;
```

Which outputs:

| d | TraditionalMethod | YourDAXTranslated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 2017-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 2019-06-01 | 2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 2020-02-13 | 2018-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 2020-10-11 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-01 | 2017-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-04-01 00:00:00 |
| 2021-07-22 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 |

---

However, I would suggest that you may be better served by creating a Dates Table to which you apply filters and from which you `join` to your transactional data to return the values you require.  In an appropriately configured environment this will make full use of available indexes and should provide very good performance.

A very basic tally table approach to generate such a Dates Table is as follows, which returns all dates and their fiscal year start dates for `2015-01-01` to `2042-05-18`:

```
with t as (select t from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as t(t))
    ,d as (select dateadd(day,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,'20150101') as d from t,t t2,t t3,t t4)
select d as DateValue
      ,case when month(d) < 4
            then datetime2fromparts(year(d)-1,4,1,0,0,0,0,0)
            else datetime2fromparts(year(d),4,1,0,0,0,0,0)
            end as FinancialYearStart
from d
order by DateValue;
```

Comment: Hi iamdave - thanks for taking a look at this for me! I was hoping to use GETDATE so that the date range isn't static but changes with time without further intervention from me and use it in a BETWEEN statement similar to the DAX- which is very short and elegant imo. Is there a similar method in t-sql which is just as "short and sweet"?

Comment: @Patrick I have given you the code to do that two different ways in my first script, just replace the column name `d` with `getdate()` and move the expression into your `where` clause.

Comment: Pasting the code into the WHERE clause resulted in an error because aliases can't exist in a WHERE clause (apparently)? So I made it part of the SELECT statement then added "Calendar_date>=alias". That also caused an error because the SELECT statement is processed after the WHERE clause so it couldn't find a column named alias. The solution ended up being wrapping the whole thing in another SELECT statement and adding "Calendar_date>=alias" to the 2nd WHERE clause...then it worked like a charm! I will try to post the exact solution later for anyone having the same problem.

Comment: @Patrick to make it work as a single statement, just remove the `as columnalias` part when used in the `where` clause...  Having this as a subselect is total overkill.  I would advise actually exploring what the errors you get mean rather than just trying things until it works.  The time taken to understand what is actually going on will pay you back many times over in the longer term.